# New to Gerrithub.io shows: Code shows 'Merged' in GerritHub.io, but still does NOT gets reflected in github master repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have my code in github repository which I used to check pull/push codes.

Now I have configured the gerrit in front of github for code review:

Way I pull the code and push for review is:

```
git clone https://review.gerrithub.io/testGitHubUser/TestGitHubProject
git reviw -s
```

- then I made some changes in one of file…
- then added the file using : git add –p
- then committed the file uses:  git commit –m “xyzmsg”

After this I have tried two different paths:

```
Path 1 :  git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Path 2 :   git review -R

Both cases I see  a change created in gerrithub.io... and it shows my changes..
I have reviewed myself as +2…
Then it shows reviewed as well as verified.
Also have hit some button to publish .. submit as well.

Now it shows status as ‘Merged’ and has following msgs :

```
Patch Set 1: Code-Review+2 Verified+1
Change has been successfully merged
```

**Problem is with NONE of above approaches, 
    I see code in Git hub master repo.
How would it start showing in github repo master? 
Do i have to manually git push in 'github' master repo now?**

Comment: I got able to resolve it. Process is pull from github (NOT gerrithub). then add gerrit remote and then do git review.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that your project in GerritHub has files with too large size for GitHub - if this is the case, then autoreplica service from GerritHub to GitHub will stop without warning - to start it again then you have to clean project from too large files

Here is how you can remove files larger than 1Mb:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'find ./ -size +1M -delete' HEAD
```